# ¿Como cambiar idioma a timeago siendo usado en react?

Tags: reactjs

Soy novato en react.js y a un componente le he agregado la fecha formateada con la libreria timeago.js, pero por default la fecha aparece en ingles. En el readme de github explican como cambiarle:

> https://github.com/hustcc/timeago.js/blob/master/README_zh.md

pero no se exactamente como hacerlo.

Alguno que lo haya logrado?.

Gracias!

Comment: Deberás editar por favor y mostrar como has tratado de implementarlo y los errores obtenidos hasta el momento

Comment: Bonito detalle la documentación en chino, lol

Answer (score 0):

En la documentación proponen lo siguiente, solo tienes que cambiar el contenido en inglés por el que quieras en español, espero te sirva.

```
import { format, register } from 'timeago.js';

// the local dict example is below.
const localeFunc = (number, index, total_sec) => {
  // number: the timeago / timein number;
  // index: the index of array below;
  // total_sec: total seconds between date to be formatted and today's date;
  return [
    ['just now', 'right now'],
    ['%s seconds ago', 'in %s seconds'],
    ['1 minute ago', 'in 1 minute'],
    ['%s minutes ago', 'in %s minutes'],
    ['1 hour ago', 'in 1 hour'],
    ['%s hours ago', 'in %s hours'],
    ['1 day ago', 'in 1 day'],
    ['%s days ago', 'in %s days'],
    ['1 week ago', 'in 1 week'],
    ['%s weeks ago', 'in %s weeks'],
    ['1 month ago', 'in 1 month'],
    ['%s months ago', 'in %s months'],
    ['1 year ago', 'in 1 year'],
    ['%s years ago', 'in %s years']
  ][index];
};
// register your locale with timeago
register('es_ES', localeFunc);

// use it
format('2016-06-12', 'es_ES');
```